# Remove class if user clicks outside of div

Tags: jquery, search, input

I have a search input and I hid the submit button. Instead, when the user presses enter, a dropdown appears with the result using the following js:

```
$(function() {
  $("form input").keypress(function (e) {
    if ((e.which && e.which == 13) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 13)) {
      $(this).next("#searchResult").addClass('show');
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  });
});
```

How do I ensure that the class of `.show` is removed if the user clicks outside of `#searchResult`?

Comment: Depends, should this happen any time the div is not clicked on, or on if the div has focus first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could utilize the `blur` event to detect when an element looses focus:

```
$("#searchResult").on( "blur", function(){
  // The users focus is no longer on this element!
});
```

You could also write this as:

```
$("#searchResult").blur( function(){
  // The users focus is no longer on this element!
});
```

This of course is assuming that the `#searchResult` element had the users focus to start with.

Reference:

- [`blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/)

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this,

```
 $("body:not(#searchResult)").click(function(){
     $("#searchResult").removeClass("show");
 });
```

Comment: You should mention here that *any* click, *anywhere* outside of the element at *any time* will trigger the callback and remove the class (even if the class has already been removed).